# code in objective to send(smtp) and receive (pop3) mail need to execute for any os

Tags: c++, smtp, pop3

need a simple application code in objective c for sending(SMTP) and receiving(POP3) of mails it should execute in any operating system .

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. You need to make the effort to figure out the problem first and then if you have specific questions you can ask them here.

Comment: I need some guidance of how to start?

Answer (score 0):

If you need cross-platform, I would stick to Qt and use this library:

https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtMail

I've used library for `xlsx` from this user and it works marvelous, so probably this one should also works properly, but never testes.

BTW: i put my answer to C++ solution, but yo have probably tag missmatch (you tagged c++, but described problem for objective C)